# Experimenting with id3 algorithm on iris and soyabean dataset giving error in Weka

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, weka

Am trying to test id3 algorithm on iris and soyabean dataset in [Weka](http://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/) Experimenter.

[image]

But `id3` algorithm when RUN, gives the following error:

```
weka.classifiers.trees.Id3: Cannot handle numeric attributes!
```

Upon searching in Google for the above error, I found this question: [Weka J48 Classifier: Cannot handle numeric class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932888/weka-j48-classifier-cannot-handle-numeric-class)

But am not sure how to use that accepted answer, since am doing the experimenting via the Weka Experimenter GUI!

Comment: definitely you can run that command to convert features to binary. then you will be able to load into weka and run j48.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The process would be outlined as below:**

- Open the Iris File (or any data file) that you would like to convert.
- Select the Filter that you would like to apply to your data (In this case, NumericToBinary is Selected)
- Change the settings of the filter as required
- Click on the 'Apply' Button to apply the changes to the dataset.

[image]

- You should see some changes to the dataset like the image below.
- Click on the 'Save...' Button and save the data to another file.
- close the Explorer

[image]

- Open the Experimenter from Weka
- Click the 'New' button, then set the Results ARFF Destination File
- Under the 'Datasets' Group, click 'Add New...', then add the modified ARFF Data File
- Under the 'Algorithms' Group, click 'Add New...' and select your algorithms

[image]

- Under the Run Tab, click the 'Start' Button.
- You should then see 0 errors as shown below:

[image]

Please note that the data filter used here is probably not very effective for modelling the problem (as all attributes appear to return true), so other filters may be better suited for this problem.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be working without errors now. I tested the dataset with three algorithms - JRip, id3 and j48. All three are giving the same output of 33.33 : http://i.imgur.com/rZevku9.png What other filter would be the best that you will suggest?

Comment: As was shown in my third image, the NumericToBinary makes attribute values false when the value is exactly zero, which is no good in this case as all attribute values are zero, which means that you will always get a low accuracy.  I usually pre-process my data outside of Weka, then import as required for modelling.  I think Discretize might help as you can determine the number of buckets per attribute that you believe may be best, and adjust as required for the model.